# Rotate and flip square (texture quad) by reordering its four corners

Tags: rotation, coordinates

I have a square defined by its four corners in ccw order starting at top left. So I basically have a coordinate array 
[TL, BL, BR, TR]
Its used for 2d texture coordinates, but that does not effect the question much.
I want to apply rotations by 90° and flipping horizontally and vertically to these coordinates. I want to do that by specifying a "transform" that holds the number of right or left 90° rotations and flags for h/v flip. Then I want to use that transform to copy the coordinates to a new location with a new order based on the transformations. So rot_0/xflip_0/yflip_1 would result in 
[TR, BR, TL, BL]
(I usually define a flip as reflection along the named axis, but that is just nomenclature stuff.) 

How can I create the corresponding order of coordinates without writing down all cases in a long list? I'm flexible with the number of 90° rotations (3/4/unlimited) that can be specified and I'm also ok with either multiple different transforms giving the same result or with a selector that only contains the minimum specifications to cover all possible transforms.
What are the minim transformations needed to reach all end states? Is rotation in two/one direction and flipping along a single axis enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like

```
Math.abs(invert*3 - ((coord + rot) % 4)));
```

can do the trick.
We have four corners and four slots where they can be placed. That gives a basic set of 4! permutations. However 2/3 of this set do not result in the correct order of the texture corners. The only acceptable orders are the original CCW order in four rotations and the inverted CW order also in four rotations. That means we need four rotations and a flip along the up-vector to reach all transformations.
To calculate the rotation it is enough to simply shift/rotate the array itself. So each entry in the target array becomes coord+rot and to keep things in a loop the modulo 4 can be used.
To flip along the up-vector we have to invert the order, which can be done via 3-coord. If we want to use a 0/1 invert parameter we need to handle negative values, hence the abs() method.
**Q: Is there a different way to handle this? A formula that does not require the evaluation of a condition?**
I do not want to evaluate that abs() condition every time I update texture coords and I do not want to store the transformed texture coords anywhere besides on the GPU. So I actually ended up filling a short table with all 8 transforms. Using a loop for that got quite ugly

```
for (int invert = 0; invert < 2; invert++)
    for (int shift = 0; shift < 4; shift++) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int coord = 0; coord < 4; coord++) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(invert*3 - ((coord + shift) % 4)));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

So I simply initialize an array with the 8 transforms manually.

```
char texTransform[8 * 4] = {    0, 1, 2, 3,
                                1, 2, 3, 0,
                                2, 3, 0, 1,
                                3, 0, 1, 2,
                                3, 2, 1, 0,
                                2, 1, 0, 3,
                                1, 0, 3, 2,
                                0, 3, 2, 1
                        };
```

and calculate the lookup for the specific transform based on the rotation and flip parameters.

```
public static int textureTransform(int rot, int flip){
    int tf = rot % 4 + (flip % 2) * 4;
    return ( tf >= 0 ) ? tf : 0;
}
```

Copying the texture coordinates then just requires a lookup of the corner order based on the transform index parameter. (JNI code in my case)

```
void nativeCopyFrameCoords(JNIEnv *env, jclass cl, jobject src, jint srcOffset, jobject dst,  jint dstOffset, jint tf)
  {
           float* pSrc = (float*) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress( env, src );
           float* pDst = (float*) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress( env, dst );

           char* selector = texTransform+tf*4;

           pDst[dstOffset +0] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[0]*2];
           pDst[dstOffset +1] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[0]*2 +1];

           pDst[dstOffset +2] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[1]*2];
           pDst[dstOffset +3] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[1]*2 +1];

           pDst[dstOffset +4] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[2]*2];
           pDst[dstOffset +5] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[2]*2 +1];

           pDst[dstOffset +6] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[3]*2];
           pDst[dstOffset +7] = pSrc[srcOffset + selector[3]*2 +1];
  }
```

(If no transform is required a call to memcopy should be used instead of setting the values one by one. `memcpy( &pDst[dstOffset], &pSrc[srcOffset], sizeof(float) * 8 );`)